# Adding record to multiple tables simultaneously

Tags: mysql

I am wondering if there is a way to create a new record across multiple tables at once ie
I have one table - customers, with field "ID" that is an auto_increment (primary ID) that when created I would like another autoinc primary field in separate table to create the matching record when the first record is created. (plus a few other records potentially linked via the same id) ie synchronously.

Or do I have to create the customer first and then, using the autoinc value, create the other linked tables record??

Comment: SQL only allows an insert to one table at a time. You could possibly enclose all related inserts in a transaction or possibly a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/triggers.html) that inserts the matching records after the primary record is inserted.

Comment: But would this still need the first ID the be created first, I am looking for something that, as the best as I can put, syncs and auto increment across multiple tables. Is what you are suggesting any different from performing an insert statement just after the creation of the first, except that it is triggered server side rather than needing the actual second statement to "come" from somewhere (program, app, form submission etc)

Comment: A trigger allows you to tell the database, essentially, "when a new row is inserted, add a new row in another table." The new row information can include part of the first record, e.g. its ID.